# Recognize a var created outside a click function

Tags: jquery, variables, click

I have two click functions referencing the same string, which I am trying to store in a variable  - for the same reason. I have this code:

```
<script>
  var changeValidity = $(this).parent().find('.checkbox-button').toggleClass('input-valid input-invalid');

  $(document).on('click','.checkbox-button.input-invalid',function() {
     changeValidity;
  });

  $(document).on('click','.checkbox-button.input-valid',function() {
    var selectedItems = $(this).parent().find('.input-valid.checked').length;

    if (selectedItems < 1){
      changeValidity;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Everything works as expected if I replace changeValidity, with what i'm attempting to store in the variable. But when stored in the variable - the string is out of scope for both click functions. Im not sure how to get around this... Any thoughts?

Comment: `changeValidity;` does nothing.  It's not a function but even if it was, you haven't called it.

Comment: @JamesMontagne, has it right, `changeValidity` is just sitting there.  Not being set to anything, not setting anything.  What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I know its not a function. Its a variable im trying to call into a function. The question is how...

Comment: I believe the issue is that $(this).parent().find('.checkbox-button').toggleClass('input-valid input-invalid'); is not properly defined at the point it is called. Because it has no reference point.

Im just wondering if there is a way to define it, without placing the same string in both functions. Im trying to avoid duplicating the string

Comment: The answer was to create a function and set a parameter. Sorry, I just had a little trouble explaining what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the visibility of your variable, or with your functions not "recognizing" it. Both functions can see and access that variable just fine.

Your problem is that you're querying DOM elements before they exist in the DOM.

Move your code into a `$(document).ready` callback.

It works if you "replace changeValidity with what I'm attempting to store in the variable" because you're (presumably) moving the querying into the event handler, at which point the elements will exist.

Comment: That should not be an issue. The script is running at bottom of page, after everything loads.

Comment: Figured it out. Had to store the string in a function and give a perameter to set $(this) on click.

`function changeValidity($this){
      $this.parent().find('.checkbox-button').toggleClass('input-valid input-invalid');
    }`